# what is this maven certification error indicates?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-plugin

[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:dynamoWork:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.0.RELEASE from/to artie (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 2]

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy? Also post your Java and Maven versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you are behind a proxy. You need to use your organisation's mirror site in settings.xml, pass mirror site's id/password and also install the site's certificates to your jre\lib\security\cacert file.