# Maven cannot downlad dependencies/plugins from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: java, maven

I've got following error when I'm trying to build my project:

`Failed to collect dependencies at org.msgpack:jackson-dataformat-msgpack:jar:0.8.17 -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:pom:2.9.9 from/to maven (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I read that the problem is with  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 and I need to change it to https. Done that, still it doesn't work. Then I found another suggestion in google -> add the maven certificate with keytool & restart. Done that. Still doesn't work. Asked a colleague to send me theirs repo and it worked (ofc, there're all the dependencies). Then I wanted to introduce categories in our junit tests, so I added surefire plugin and this time the problem is similar:

```
Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: 
Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-grouper:jar:2.12.4: Failed to retrieve POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-grouper:jar:2.12.4: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-grouper:pom:2.12.4 from/to maven (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: u
nable to find valid certification path to requested target [ERROR]   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-grouper:jar:2.12.4
[ERROR]
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   maven (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR]   apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR]         1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
[ERROR]         2) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit47:jar:2.12.4
[ERROR]         3) org.apache.maven.surefire:common-junit48:jar:2.12.4
```

So then I decide to go and download one by one, but it's a hell and I prefer to fix this issue instead of manually download everything.

Comment: You need to verify that maven is using the JDK with the certificate, you can do that with the command `mvn -v`. Another alternative is to configure as mirror the insecure HTTP repository, http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/. But it's better to go to the https one. More details here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334

Comment: Maybe have a look here if it's same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53282526/what-is-this-maven-certification-error-indicates?rq=1

Comment: @SHoko it's the correct jdk. I'll tried the mirroring too

Comment: @EFOE until now i didnt thought about the proxy thing. We were without proxy, but I'll ask IT guys about it, could be the case.

Comment: @EFOE it's not the proxy(we dont have one), but we have ForcePoint. Could it be the problem?

Comment: ty for the help guys, it turns out that is our firewall that causes all the problems.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was with our firewall - somehow it blocks requests to all maven repos. When I asked the ITs to stop it and test it, maven was able to download everything from the standard maven repo (the one with https)

Comment: I had the same problem. It turns out that I was connected using the VPN of the company. Temporarily disconnecting the VPN allowed me to download the dependencies.